# Update a Mobilefirst 8.0 Proguard application

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I want apply the latest fix, which resolves some crashes problems, on my server. After the fix is applied, how do I update my existing Mobilefirst 8.0 Proguard application?

Answer (score 1):

When a new fix applied to server environment, the existing application should be updated following the steps below.

1.Update proguard-project-mfp.txt (ProGuard Rules) file with the property below.

```
-keepclassmembers class * implements
javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory {
         private     javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory delegate;
    }
```

2.Enable Proguard in the build.gradle file of the app module.

To
enable  Proguard include the following within the android {} tag of the build.gradle file

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles  getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
   }
```

Further information:  https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/09/19/mfp-80-obfuscating-android-code-with-proguard/